# Updating SSIS Package when datatype for SQL column is changed

Tags: sql-server, ssis

We have to update the datatype for a column in SQL table which is used a source in a SSIS package. But when I run the SSIS package after updating the data type it fails due to datatype mismatch.

How can I have SSIS package recompile/revalidate the sourcecode so it doesn't fail?

Comment: I assume you've updated the source column, but not the rest in the data flow. You need to update **all** appearances of the column's datatype in your data flow. *If* the destination column type can't be implicitly cast to (maybe it was previously `int` and now a `date`), then you'll need to also add a Data Conversion Transformation or Derived Column Transformation.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dfb74be5-aac3-424a-b4f3-fd399897b768/need-to-change-datatype-from-dti4-to-dtstr-in-ssis?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Answer (score 0):

You will need to open the SSIS package itself.  From this point, go to any component that uses this object, right-click this and select **Show Advanced Editor...**  then press the Refresh button on the Connection Manager pane to update the metadata.  I'd also recommend double-checking any column mappings to verify that the data types and lengths are compatible.

Answer (score -1):

You can open the existing package and run a data conversion or simply create a new one and overwrite the existing one with the conversion.

[image]